# Click on label Selenium automation

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having problems with being able to select the RUC option in this software with selenium, the labels do not contain ids that differentiate them and the classes are the same:

[HTML elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WfgA.png)

I am using the following code but it doesn't work for me:

```
label_tipo_documento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="form-group-tipo_documento"]//div[@class="col-sm-3"]//label[@class="radio-inline"][2]')
print(label_tipo_documento.text)
label_tipo_documento.click()
```

I try to select the 2nd option within the labels [2] (RUC) and I get the following message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="form-group-tipo_documento"]//div[@class="col-sm-3"]//label[@class="radio-inline"][2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

However, when I do it with [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WfgA.png)] instead of [2], it finds a value:

```
DNI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element associated with the text as **RUC** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` for the `<input>`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#form-group-tipo_documento label.radio-inline > input[value='RUC']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `<label>` *text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='form-group-tipo_documento']//label[@class='radio-inline' and contains(., 'RUC')]/input").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#form-group-tipo_documento label.radio-inline > input[value='RUC']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='form-group-tipo_documento']//label[@class='radio-inline' and contains(., 'RUC')]/input"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

Use following `xpath` to click on 2nd radio button.

```
label_tipo_documento = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[./input[@value='RUC']]")
print(label_tipo_documento.text)
label_tipo_documento.click()
```

---

If yon want to use indexing then try this code.

```
label_tipo_documento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@id="form-group-tipo_documento"]//div[@class="col-sm-3"]//label[@class="radio-inline"])[2]')
print(label_tipo_documento.text)
label_tipo_documento.click()
```

Comment: This would work, might be better to use find_elements_by_xpath and then do the indexing in python rather than xpath.

Answer (score -1):

```
//div[@id="form-group-tipo_documento"]//div[@class="col-sm-3"]//label[@class="radio-inline"][2]
```

Means that you want to select *second descendant label of `div` node* (it has only one descendant label). While you need to select *second **occurrence** of label*. So either try

```
label_tipo_documento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@id="form-group-tipo_documento"]//div[@class="col-sm-3"]//label[@class="radio-inline"])[2]')
```

or

```
label_tipo_documento = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="form-group-tipo_documento"]//div[@class="col-sm-3"]//label[@class="radio-inline"]')[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Good morning.

So, based on your image, I believe the `xpath` that you would need is this.

```
# XPATH
//div[contains(@id, 'tipo_documento')]//label[@class='radio-inline']//input[@value='DNI']
```

Based off of this `xpath`, you should make a variable for the `radio button` that you want to click and then execute it with the following command.

```
myValue = "DNI"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'tipo_documento')]//label[@class='radio-inline']//input[@value='{0}']".format(myValue)).click()
```

Based off of this code, you could change "DNI" to "RUC" or "CEX" and you should be good to go.